# Process.Start() is not releasing file handles

Tags: c#, process

I have some code that is creating a PNG file of a graph of Nodes using GraphViz's dot program.  This first time through the code works perfectly.  However, if I try to run the method again it fails because the file is still considered in use by windows.

Here is the relevant code to start the dot.exe process:

```
private void MakePng()
{
    string args = "-o" + graphPath + " -Tpng  " + dotPath;

    Process process = new Process();

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = VizGraphPath;
    info.Arguments = args;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    process.StartInfo = info;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
    process.Start();

}
private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UpdateCanvas();
}
```

The various string variables named xxxPath are just static strings to the correct file paths.  When the program starts up and I run this code everything works perfectly.  But if I reset my graph and try to run this set of code again it fails to create a new PNG.  The old one is still there.  To test something out I added this line:

```
private void MakePng()
{
    string args = "-o" + graphPath + " -Tpng  " + dotPath;
    File.Delete(graphPath);
```

Which works the first time through. But the second time it throws a Exception stating File is still in use.  So I'm guessing somehow when the Process I start exits, the File Handle it created is still in use even though it exited?  Any suggestions about how to figure out why its still in use or how to fix it?

My UpdateCanvas function is also accessing the file that is locked:

```
public void UpdateCanvas()
{
  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(graphPath);
  pbCanvas.Image = image;  
}
```

Do i need to something when loading a bitmap from a file to release the file?
It was indeed the Bitmap locking the file.  I had to dispose of it before the file would be unlocked.

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat the tag information in the title. The tag system here is extremely effective and doesn't need any assistance. Thanks.

Comment: This line was probably also unnecessary :The tag system here is extremely effective and doesn't need any assistance.  Comes off a little smarmy :)

Comment: If you were aware of that, you wouldn't have repeated tag info in your title, I wouldn't have edited to remove it, and I wouldn't have needed to point it out to you. :-) Rather than taking offense, learn to accept constructive advice and information. The tag system here works, and you don't need to regurgitate the tag info in the title of your posts. The tag will get it to the attention of those who monitor the tag and let them know it's here.

Comment: I did take constructive criticism.  I up voted your comment.  I was just suggesting that this comment: The tag system here is extremely effective and doesn't need any assistance.Thanks was the unnecessary part.  I only took offense at the sarcastic part.  The first line was extremely useful and helpful.  It was just a little constructive criticism for you.  Which you can accept or take offense at.

Comment: Sorry. I thought  it was clear I was explaining *why* it was not necessary to repeat the tag info. Didn't realize it would come off in any other way. It seems to be pretty politely phrased; there was nothing personal or offensive or rude intended.

Comment: No problem.  It probably was just taken the wrong way. Thanks again for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is locked by `new Bitmap`.
Rewrite it with:

```
public void UpdateCanvas()
{
    Image img;
    using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(graphPath))
    {
        img = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
    }
    pbCanvas.Image = img;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Process class implements IDisposable, so you need to despose resources. Also, you can add WatForExit method to be sure, your process finished:

```
private void MakePng()
{
    string args = "-o" + graphPath + " -Tpng  " + dotPath;

    using(Process process = new Process())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = VizGraphPath;
        info.Arguments = args;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process.StartInfo = info;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit(10*1000); //10 seconds
    }

    UpdateCanvas();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but this code also leaves the file locked.  Even added process.Dispose() after the WaitForExit()  Though oddly it instantly displayed my PNG first time through.  I would have expected a 10 second delay as I thought WaitForExit would block the thread?

Comment: @TonyChamberlain the time that is being passed in is a timeout not a total time to wait. If the process exits before the 10 secconds are up it will continue early.

Comment: Is it possible the main thread of my program somehow has the file locked.  Seems very strange a process that exited would have a file lock still.  I can even wait multiple minutes before trying to run this again and it always stays locked after the first run.  (its being run through a button callback)

Comment: @TonyChamberlain well, if this does not help, problem is somewhere else. Please, revise your code that works with file. I think, if you add full source sode , we can find a problem

Comment: @Backs Adding the only other code that does anything with the file.

Comment: @TonyChamberlain check my another answer, I sure, it will help

Comment: Yep figured that out right after i posted thanks!   Is there a way to mark a question answered?

Comment: @TonyChamberlain you marked one answer as the best - that's enough